# Adding instances to Azure websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

From our Azure environment we are calling an external webservice which does IP filtering. We are currently running on two instances of our website and the outgoing IP addresses for those sites have been added to the FW on the external webservice.

If we need to scale out, by adding say 2 more instances, will/is there a risk the new instances get a new outgoing IP?

The website in itself has a fixed public IP (to allow for DNS), but we see that one of the instances gives a different IP, so if we setup autoscaling will we loose complete control (not that we have any) of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview for the list of IP addresses that can be used for outgoing connections from Azure websites.